# django debugging help

Tags: python, django

I am new to python, django and wing ide. I come from .net. I need to debug a django web app and I am not sure where the entry point is so I can start debugging right from the beginning. Please advise.

Does the app have to be in the mysites folder i configured during the configuring django? Or it can be anywhere?

I have **init**, main, manage, settings, settings_local and urls files in the initial directory of this app.

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn't look like debugging issue, more like the lack of basic django/python knowledge. This is fine and every django/python developer pass this stage but I think stackoverflow is not the best place to get this knowledge, django tutorial, djangobook.com and diveintopython.org are far better starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). The second part covers the basics of debugging.